# p:ajax blur event not triggered at first time primefaces jsf 2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<p:inputText id="reportDesc"
                                value="#{reportBean.report.reportDesc}" rows="4" cols="20"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Report Desc is Required"
                                styleClass="">
                                <p:ajax event="blur" update=":dataForm :growlForm:growl"
                                    listener="#{reportBean.handleDialogClose}" />
                                <f:attribute name="reportId"
                                    value="#{reportBean.report.reportId}"></f:attribute>
                            </p:inputText>
```

> ajax listener not triggered at first time.

Comment: And then ajax listener is triggered ?(second time)

Comment: Yes. Its working now, put  "ajax=true" in loading page action button to  resolve this issue.

Comment: You post answer to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

I also have familiar problem with you, because, with blur event, update attribute is ineffective, you should use "dateselect" event instead of.
But, if you still refer "blur" event, you should create new remoteCommand to update expected element. This remote command will be call in "oncomplete" of blur event

```
<h:form>
    <p:calendar
        value="#{foo.dtValidade}">
        <p:ajax
            event="blur" listener="#{foo.updateCriteria}" oncomplete="rc"/>
    </p:calendar>

    <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="criteriosDataGridTeste" >

    <h:panelGroup id="criteriosDataGridTeste">
        <td><h:selectOneMenu value="#{foo.idtpresult}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="ok" itemValue="ok" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="not ok" itemValue="not ok" />
            </h:selectOneMenu></td>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```